# Why is $c^{T}x=\sum_{i=0}^{4}y_{i}A_{i\cdot}z$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-transformations, linear-programming

Let $z \in \mathbb R^{4}$. Say I am given:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}−1 & −1 & 0 & −6 \\
−6 &−2& 3& −11 \\
1& 7& −10& −2 \\
3& 1& −1& 12\end{pmatrix}$

and $c:=\begin{pmatrix}
47\\
93\\
17\\
−93
\end{pmatrix}$

Let $y:=\begin{pmatrix}  y_{1} \\ y_{2} \\ y_{3} \\ y_{4}\end{pmatrix}$ be the solution to $Ay=c$

It follows that $y=\begin{pmatrix}  -3 \\ -2 \\ -2 \\ -7\end{pmatrix}$.

> I am told that $c^{T}z=\sum_{i = 1}^{4}y_{i}A_{\{i\}\cdot}z$ but I do
>   not see why this is the case, note that $A_{\{i\}\cdot}$ denotes the
>   $i-$th row.

I know that $y$ signfies the vector containing the scalar quantities that form a linear combination of the columns(!) of $A$, meaning:

$y_{1}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-6\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}+y_{2}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-2\\7\\1\end{pmatrix}+y_{3}\begin{pmatrix}0\\3\\-10\\-1\end{pmatrix}+y_{4}\begin{pmatrix}-6\\-11\\-2\\12\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}47\\93\\17\\-93\end{pmatrix}$

But $A_{\{i\}\cdot}$ represents the $i-$th row, so how does $c^{T}z=\sum_{i = 1}^{4}y_{i}A_{\{i\}\cdot}z$ make any sense at all?

Comment: Hint: Think about how standard matrix multiplication works. Now, transpose the matrix after the multiplication. Notice how rows become columns and columns become rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$
Ay = c.
$$
Transpose to get
$$
c^t = y^t A^t
$$
Check to see that this means that 
$$
c^{t} = \sum_{i = 1}^{4}y_{i} A_{\{i\}}
$$
Now noting that both $c^t$ and the expression on the right hand side are $1 \times 4$ row vectors, take a matrix product with an arbitrary $4 \times 1$ column vector $z$ to get
\begin{align}
c^{t}z 
&= \biggl(\sum_{i = 1}^{4}y_{i} A_{\{i\}}\biggr) z\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{4}\biggl(y_{i} A_{\{i\}}z \biggr) & \text{by linearity of matrix mult'n}\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{4}y_{i} \biggl(A_{\{i\}}z \biggr) & \text{by linearity of matrix mult'n again}
\end{align}

Your text has perhaps misused the centered dot notation, i.e., $\cdot$, to indicate a matrix product rather than a dot-product, or maybe it defines dot-products between row and column vectors. Either way, this is what's really meant.